# BeautifulSoup: Why is find_all() with a list of tags much slower than searching for each tag separately and appending it to result?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm wondering why is this code:

```
tags = ['a', 'h1', 'style', 'nav', 'footer']
result = []
for t in tags:
    for el in soup.find_all(t):
        result.append(el)
```

much faster than this one:

```
tags = ['a', 'h1', 'style', 'nav', 'footer']
result = []
for el in soup.find_all(tags):
    result.append(el)
```

It doesn't make much sense to me as I'd expect that the second variant is faster. (I'd expect that the first variant does 5 loops and second would do just 1 through the tree.)

Code I used for timing:

```
import timeit

setup = '''
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = get_some_html_content()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
'''

stmt_1 = '''
result = []
for t in ['a', 'h1', 'style', 'nav', 'footer']:
    for el in soup.find_all(t):
        result.append(el)
'''

stmt_2 = '''
result = []
for el in soup.find_all(['a', 'h1', 'style', 'nav', 'footer']):
    result.append(el)
'''
print(timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt=stmt_1, number=100))
print(timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt=stmt_2, number=100))
```

Comment: Can you show the code that demonstrates how you timed this?

Comment: @DarkKnight Sure I updated the question ^